# Calculate the sum of two numbers using thread

Tags: c, unix, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I have this little program I wrote to read two numbers from a user and calculate their sum using a thread function, which is also responsible for displaying the result on the screen.

```
int global[2];

void *sum_thread(void *arg)
{
    int *args_array;
    args_array = *(int**)arg;

    int n1,n2,sum;
    n1=args_array[0];
    n2=args_array[1];
    sum = n1+n2;

    printf("N1 + N2 = %d\n",sum);

    return NULL;
}

int main() 
{
    printf("First number: ");
    scanf("%d",&global[0]);

    printf("Second number: ");
    scanf("%d",&global[1]);

    pthread_t tid_sum;
    pthread_create(&tid_sum,NULL,sum_thread,(void*)&global);
    pthread_join(tid_sum,NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run the code, it does not work properly due to a segmentation fault. I suppose I am trying to access/use unallocated memory. Should I allocate it with malloc or is there other things I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the array, `global` points to the base address of the array. You can simply pass that and use the same inside your thread function.

However, just to mention a logical point, if you're passing `global` as a parameter to `sum_thread()` function, it need not be a *global*.

In your code, change

```
pthread_create(&tid_sum,NULL,sum_thread,(void*)&global);
```

to

```
pthread_create(&tid_sum,NULL,sum_thread,global);
```

Then, in `sum_thread()` function

```
args_array = *(int**)arg;
```

to

```
args_array = arg;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Just for the sake of really understanding what I have changed, can you please explain me why I don't need to cast global when passing it as an argument to the thread @SouravGhosh ?

Comment: @CarlosPereira it is not about casting a _global_, the casting is simply not required. it will happen implicitly in `C`.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Does that apply to any type of argument I want to pass @SouravGhosh ?

Comment: @CarlosPereirano, that's not the case. According to `C` standard, a void` pointer is safely and implicitly casted to any type of data pointer.

Comment: @CarlosPereira Exact quote from standard, `A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.`

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience and knowledge, it really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

You pass `(void*)&global` as the thread start function's argument.  The type of `&global` is (*)int[2] -- pointer to array of two `int`.  That is different from and incompatible with `int **`, which is a pointer to a pointer to `int`.  Arrays are not pointers.

@SouravGhosh already offered a solution that gets the typing correct, and should work just fine.  I observe, however, that in this particular case it's a bit silly to pass a pointer to the global array, because the thread could instead just read the array directly:

```
void *sum_thread(void *arg)
{
    int n1,n2,sum;
    n1=global[0];
    n2=global[1];
    sum = n1+n2;

    printf("N1 + N2 = %d\n",sum);

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Ok, it makes sense thanks! About the silly part, I know that, but I'm just learning how to pass arguments between threads, thus using it anyways.